# Сравнительная степень прилагательных

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как образовать сравнительную степень след. прилагательных: малюсенький, лиловый, круглый. И вообще, можно ли от них ее образовать. Как образуется степень у прилагательных с уменьшительно-ласкательным суффиксом?

Comment: Уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс только у *малюсенького*. А с двумя другими какие проблемы? Лиловее, круглее.

Comment: Впрочем, некоторые источники говорят, что от *лиловый* ставнительная степень не образуется. Можно  ли им верить?

Comment: _М_Г: Впрочем, некоторые источники говорят, что от лиловый ставнительная степень не образуется. Можно ли им верить?_ === Я бы такими _источниками_ не пользовался.

Answer (score 3):

[лиловый](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B5)
Сравнительная степень: лиловее; лиловей; полиловее; полиловей.

Имеются разные мнения по поводу постановки ударения.
Викисловарь: [лилове́е](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9).
Словарь трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке (К. С. Горбачевич):
[лило́вее](https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/3225/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9) (неправильно лилове́е). [Я склоняюсь к этому варианту.]

*Labemol же было для меня пределом лиловизны: **лиловее** тарусских ирисов, лиловее страховской тучи, лиловее сегюровской «Forêt des Lilas»* (М. Цветаева).

[круглый](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5)
Сравнительная степень: круглее; круглей; покруглее; покруглей.

*Но в конце они сделались еще **круглей** раза в четыре, хотя вначале казалось, что достигнута полная округлость и **круглее** быть просто нельзя*.
[В. Рогожин. Филфак. Записки скверного мальчишки](https://books.google.ee/books?id=hJI4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=vjH9Sxp0NH&sig=ACfU3U2AQ59Jr39_Xb7QlQqHHhorDLKCnQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjziY7k3PzfAhWviqYKHVnnDag4FBDoATAJegQIABAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5&f=false)

Малю́сенький — *разг*. уменьш. от маленький; очень маленький.
Сравнительная степень не образуется (ну, если только какой-нибудь окказионализм).